# CardDav server library

Tags: java, web-applications, vcf-vcard, carddav

I'm building a java based web app.
In the web app, we can create contact. We have already implemented an export to vcard.

Now we would like to be able to synchronize with a contact manager (like Zimbra)  the contact created on the app. To do so i thought about using a carddav server.

And i would like to expose a carddav server embedded inside my webapp.

The Questions are:

- Is that possible?
- How could one achieve that?

By the way, I'm not sure that's the best way to do. So if you have any proposition ...

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use http://milton.io/

Milto.io is a Java Webdav Server Library which supports CardDav.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated a webdav servlet to support carddav: https://github.com/corinis/webdav-servlet